# How to call a method on click on textfiled rathe than text changes

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextfield

I want to move the view when TextField is clicked but it works only on `textDidChange` when we change text or write anything so how to call method when we click the TextField.

```
 -(void)textFieldTextDidChange:(UITextField*)tf{

    [self  showAnimationPests];


}


    -(void) showAnimationPests{


      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-300,1024,768);
                 }];

     }
```

instead of textchange i want on textfield click

In .h file

```
    IBOutlet UIButton*button1;
IBOutlet UIButton*button2;
IBOutlet UIButton*button3;
IBOutlet UIButton*button4;
IBOutlet UIButton*button5;
IBOutlet UIButton*button6;
IBOutlet UIButton*button7;
IBOutlet UIButton*button8;
IBOutlet UIButton*button9;
IBOutlet UIButton*button10;

    @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton*button1;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton*button2;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton*button3;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton*button4;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton*button5;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton*button6;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton*button7;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton*button8;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton*button9;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton*button10;
```

Comment: can not clearly understand what you trying..?

Comment: Start accepting correct and helpful answers otherwise peoples will start to neglect to give you answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

delegate method. It is called when `UITextField` becomes the first responder. The moment you click in your textfield this method gets called.

Comment: thanks Rushi it worked can you help me in one thing that when change the view frame location then contents of view also changed so how to fix those things

Comment: @user1808433 : Didn't get you. You want to move content of view with view or you don't want to move content of view when view move?

Comment: @user1808433 : If you want to move both simple way of doing it is add your content on the view. So, it'll move with your view.

Comment: my content is in view it is the same view whicy befault we have when we add new UIViewController class and then add content on that usign iboutlets

Comment: How you adding your controls and you add that code in your question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23878/discussion-between-rushi-and-user1808433)

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it by using delegate method

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        [self  showAnimationPests];
    }
```

Or add tap gasture to your textField

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap)];
        [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

        [tf addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    }

- (void)handleSingleTap
    {
        [self  showAnimationPests];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this Code :

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(slideUpView:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(slideDownView:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

    -(void)slideDownView:(NSNotification*)notification
{

    [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                          delay:0.0
                        options:animationCurve
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Slide down Done..!");
                     }];
}

-(void)slideUpView:(NSNotification*)notification
{

    [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];
    //
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                          delay:0.0
                        options:animationCurve
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -keyboardFrame.size.height + 70, 320, 416);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Slide up Done..!");
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstofall add `<UITextFieldDelegate>` in your `.h` file than
in `.m` file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 yourtextfield.delegate = self;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == yourtextfield)
    {
       [self  showAnimationPests];
    }
}
-(void) showAnimationPests
{
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
             animations:^{
                 self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-300,1024,768);
             }];

 }
```